# Connecting to Cassandra Cluster instead of specific node

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to learn Cassandra and have setup a 2 node Cassandra cluster. I have written a client in Java using cassandra jdbc driver, which currently connects to a hard coded single node in the cluster. Ideally, I would like my client to connect to the "cluster" rather then a specific node.
So that client code automatically connects to other node if the first node is down.

Is this possible using cassandra jdbc driver? Currently using below code to create connection

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/testdb");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you're using the Datastax Java driver, you can get all of these benefits and more. From the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html):

> The driver has the following features:
>
> - connection pooling
> - node discovery
> - automatic failover
> - load balancing

Comment: [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html#java-driver/reference/settingUpJavaProgEnv_r.html) page is referring to download 34 jar files. 

Do we really need these many jars? If yes, then where can I find all these jar? please suggest.

Comment: Specifically, when your code first connects, you give it a list of nodes it can try to connect to.

Comment: @user2034519 - no need to download these dependencies separately as long as you have a cassandra environment set up already. Aside from the driver itself, these jars are already part of Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

What is your language? If you're using Java, I suggest for Hector framework. 
http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/index.html
I think it's very good for correspond on Cassandra db.